Why can't I get liveview on my Nikon D5100?
So I found my family's old camera, a Nikon D5100. I bought a new battery for it which is the EN-EL14a. I couldn't find the original battery for this camera (EN_EL14) because it's old and the battery is "phased out" from the stores.
Then again, the pictures are great, awesome, and the battery doesn't seem to have any issues at all. But live view does not work. Whenever I try to use it, my screen goes black then all of a sudden it says "Error. Press shutter button again" or something like that. When I resolve the error then try to use live view the results are the same.
I don't know what to do because I already spent thousands, I don't want to spend any more money. I tried searching online and there's nothing. I can't see any possible solution to this problem. If any of you, please give me a tip on what to do here. I'm not sure if it's the lens, battery, or SD card because it functions perfectly fine. The thing is I think it gets stuck. Please help me.

Which lens are you using? If you take off the lens and switch to Live View, do you see the mirror move up (ie. can you see the sensor)? Any other information - camera mode P/A/S/M and any shutter, aperture or ISO settings - might also tell us something useful. And does the screen show pictures and menus (ie. the problem only happens with Live View)?

AF-S NIKKOR 18-55MM 1:3.5-5.6G NIKON DX, i was told this was the original lens from when it was bought. And yes, it only happens when i attempt to do live view.

Is your D5100's firmware up to date?
If you go to Menu > Setup > Firmware version what version do you have on your D5100?
A firmware update was needed to make the D5100 accurately gauge the charge state of an EN-EL14A.
If you have a D5100, it was with the A firmware v.1.02 / B firmware v.1.01 upgrade:
https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/20.html
It might be you're on an older version of firmware and so the camera thinks there's not enough charge in the battery to perform liveview.

So i checked this out, I'm new to cameras so idk what this means, but here's what's written: A 1.00 B 1.00 L 1.003, what to do here? I don't know how to update firmware.

And is the firmware important? Because i red online that it's a mechanical problem in the inner body of the camera. It would be a relief if it was just the firmware. I'll try asking or searching around to see if i can update it without harming it more.

@mel, the firmware may not fix the issue, but it also might, and it never hurts to keep the firmware up=to-date.  See also: "Should I worry about the firmware version on my DSLR, and if so, how do I update?". While there is a danger of bricking the camera if you interrupt the firmware update process, it's a process that's designed to be something users do.

If that's the case, how much would it take for other/professionals to update it? I don't want to risk doing it myself because I'm clumsy handed. I'll see if i have the budget to do so. Thank you!

I'm a bit sad, as is wanted to use it for photo journalism.  When i found out the firmware is behind, i had hope that the camera wasn't broken. I could use the viewfinder, but it's more convenient to use the live view right? That's why I'm trying to get it fixed. My family LOVED this camera. I want to keep its legacy :p. Plus i can't film videos, which i need for an upcoming film for a project. I hope to get it fixed.

@mel, that actually sounds like it may be more than a firmware issue; that something may be broken in hardware. In general, though, it's not more convenient to use liveview while shooting stills; you can steady the camera better (press it against your face) when using a viewfinder to compose instead of arm's length with the back LCD.

it's actually pointless now, took it to the shop and it really is broken. The mirror is broken. I'm thinking of just buying a new one.

You may want to un-accept my answer, and (after a while, you'll be able to) accept your own, since that's the real answer. Sorry to hear it's broken.
